# Double/Volume integral in parametric form

Tags: calculus, integration, euclidean-geometry, volume, parametric

> Find the volume of the tetrahedron with vertices at $(0,0,0),(a,0,0),(0,b,0),(0,0,c)$

The most straight forward approach would be evaluating the following integral in Cartesian coordinates system.
$$V=\int_0^a\int^{b(1-x/a)}_{0}\int^{c(1-x/a-y/b)}_0dzdydx=\frac{abc}{6}$$
(which I can make sense of.)

---

But I tried two alternative methods each of which involves parametric equations:

Describing the surface that joins the three vertices, with a vector equation, I got 
$$\vec{r}=(a,0,0)+\lambda(-a,b,0)+\mu(-a,0,c)=(a(1-\lambda-\mu),\lambda b,\mu c)=(x,y,z) \tag{1}$$
(here I used $\vec{AB}=(-a,b,0)$ and $\vec{AC}=(-a,0,c)$ as the two directional vectors.)

and 
$$x=a(1-\lambda-\mu),y=\lambda b, z=\mu c \tag{2}$$
as the three parametric equations that describe the surface, where $0\leq y\leq b$ and $0\leq z\leq c$ give the limits $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$ and $0\leq \mu \leq 1$.

Taking $dV=xdydz$:
$$dV=x(\lambda,\mu)\frac{dy}{d\lambda}\frac{dz}{d\mu}d\lambda d\mu=abc(1-\lambda-\mu)d\lambda d\mu \tag{3}$$
Integration yields $$V=abc\int^{\mu=1}_{\mu=0}\int^{\lambda=1}_{\lambda=0}(1-\lambda-\mu)d\lambda d\mu=0 \tag{4}$$
which is clearly wrong.

Alternatively, by taking $dV=dxdydz$, I got some rather dodgy differential terms:
$$dV=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \lambda}d\lambda+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \mu}d\mu\right)\frac{dy}{d\lambda}\frac{dz}{d\mu}d\lambda d\mu=-abc(d\lambda+d\mu)d\lambda d\mu \tag{5}$$
which has terms like $d\lambda^2$ (the square of a differential is not something I've seen before, except for $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$ but that's a different story...).

Can someone please explain where my conceptual errors lie?

Or is there a correct approach involving parametric equations?

Comment: Ummm... that's not a tetrahedron.  All your points are on a plane.

Comment: @David G. Stork Oh I see. So is there a similar (double) integral approach involving the parametric equations $(2)$ (If one insists).?

Comment: The tetrahedron has four vertices (not three). There's some information missing

Comment: @Simons-Chern You're likely forgetting the point $(0,0,c)$.

Comment: @ Mark Fantini @ lcv thanks, edited